# linking google+ page to customer site / different domain name

Tags: php, html, google-plus

i'm trying to connect my customer's webpage to my google+ business page.
so i added the following tag to the website header:

```
<link href='https://plus.google.com/{myid}' rel='publisher' />
```

the problem is that my customer's domain name is (of course) different than the one stored in my Google+ Page).

Is it possible to add that url to my Google+ Page in order the tool for structured Data will recognize it?

currently i'm getting an error:
`This is no valid Publisher markup` (it's in german originally)

any ideas how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domains have to match to verify direct linking of website with Google+ page.

Comment: seems like i can only bind one domain to each google page .. :(

Comment: Yes. It does seem that way. You can [submit feedback](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1678224?hl=en&ref_topic=3049669) to Google+.